# JSF2 ResourceBundleLoader override?

Tags: java, jsf, el, jsf-2, resourcebundle

I need to have resource messages that contain EL expressions be resolved when loaded from a ResourceBundle. Basically I have a number of properties files containing the text. Some of the text will look like the following:

welcomeText=Welcome #{userbean.name}

The only possible way I can see this working currently is implementing a custom taglib so that instead of saying:

```
<f:loadBundle var="messages" basename="application.messages"/>
```

I would have to use

```
<mytaglib:loadBundle var="messages" basename="application.messages"/>
#{messages.welcomeText}
```

Given a user with username "User1", this should output

```
Welcome User1
```

My implementation would then use a custom ResourceBundle class that would override handleGetObject, use the ELResolver to resolve variables etc....Ideas? suggestings? Implementations that are already available?

I appreciate your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather make use of [`<h:outputFormat>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/outputFormat.html) and [`<f:param>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/param.html) to display parameterized text. It's backed by the [`MessageFormat` API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html), the same rules as described in the API's javadoc will be applied.

E.g.

```
welcomeText=Welcome {0}
```

with

```
<h:outputFormat value="#{messages.welcomeText}">
    <f:param value="#{userbean.name}" />
</h:outputFormat>
```

There it is for :)

Comment: I know about MessageFormat, but I am specifically looking for a way of resolving variables from inside property files. It is possible that different locales will have different messages with different variables being used for the textual output.

Comment: Well, that pretty much tight-couples the bundle with the model. The bundle maintainer has to know precisely about the models used. By the way, you can also just use `{1}`, `{2}`, `{n}` and so on and just feed them all and clearly document which one stands for what value. The ones not specified in the bundle will be plain ignored.